# How to save data frame into specific folder based on System date in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I am working on one directory and my Python file(.ipynb) file is stored in the same directory.
Directory currently I am working = `"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\ABC\Data Science"`

After working on a data set I am dumping my data frame into new folder = `"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\ABC\Data Science\Dataset"`.

I have a requirement where I have to save the data based on Date and time.

I have used below method

```
TodaysDate = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
excelfilename_pass = TodaysDate +".csv"
passed_data.to_csv(excelfilename_pass)
```

But the above code is getting saved in `"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\ABC\Data Science"` this folder whereas I want the data frame to be saved in `"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\ABC\Data Science\Dataset"` folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the full path

```
folder_path = r"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\ABC\Data Science\Dataset"
file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "{}.csv".format(time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")))
passed_data.to_csv(file_path )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is currently in the Data Science folder, I would simply add the `dataset` to your file path.

So `excelfilename_pass = "dataset/" + TodaysDate + ".csv"`